# How to use jquery dialog('open') correctly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

dialog() is already initiated at this point with:

```
$("#repshare_dialog").dialog({autoOpen: false});
```

Next I'm trying to open a dialog box with a title, is this right?

```
$("#repshare_dialog").dialog({
    open: function(event,ui) {
        title: "foo"
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$("#repshare_dialog").dialog({ title: "foo" });
```

You only need to use the `open` event if you want to perform some action when the dialog has been opened.

Check out the [jQuery UI docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) for more options and detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use autoOpen:false, what you want is:

```
$('#repshare_dialog').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  title: 'whatever'
});
```

later

```
$('#repshare_dialog').dialog('open');
```

If for some reason you really need to set the title after the dialog has been created, you can do it between the create and the open using

```
$('#repshare_dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'Bananas in Pajamas');
```

as per [the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-option).